# Small custom video player instead thumbnail image

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I am using WordPress and I want the thumbnail image to be changed when the mouse-over action occurs.

**Scenario:**

For the video streaming, I am embedding the video URL using the jw-player.

**Question:**

Is there a way to display the video (in place of the thumbnail image) through the use of playing a series of 6 images incrementally (jumping)?

I mean, there are some new custom players that provides a rule to divide/jumping the movie in 6 parts?

It would be perfect to add some small-thumbnail-player with code like this in the thumbnail section :)

Comment: When the player is set up, it has a poster image set. It can't be changed after the player has been set up initially.